# How to commit a mutation to store whenever route changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

Is there any way to commit a mutation to store whenever the route changes **without** using a Vuex plugin to listen for `route/` mutations?

Using `vuex`, `nuxt`, `vue-router` + `vue-router-sync`.

Edit: I'm trying to commit in a different slice of the store, not just the `route` portion.

*See a lot of questions that ask the **opposite,** but not this, please keep in mind when flagging for duplicate ;).*

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve what `vue-router-sync` does by yourself without using `vue-router-sync`? What kind of mutation do you want to perform?

Comment: @DecadeMoon thanks for chiming in! I've updated the ? to be more specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just register an [`afterEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks) listener on the router and commit your mutation from there:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  store.commit('MY_MUTATION', ...)
})
```

I'm not familiar with nuxt, but this might work:

```js
// plugins/sync.js

export default ({ app: { router, store } }) => {
  router.afterEach((to, next) => {
    store.commit('MY_MUTATION', ...)
  })
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js

plugins: [
  '~plugins/sync'
]
```

Comment: sorry forgot to add that I'm using nuxt as well. It comes with a `router.js` file. Would I just have to import the store into that file and register the `afterEach` in there? I hope it isn't considered a bad practice to import the store

Comment: i ended up using a general vuex plugin to listen for route change mutation and then commit the other mutation...i like this approach better though, will give it a whirl! thanks